# Why i cant print out anything by using out.println in java servlet?

Tags: java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(  ); 

        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                                         new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

                for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                    if(!item.isFormField()){
                        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                    }
                }               
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               out.println("File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            }          

        }
```

Comment: why you think you can't use it?

Comment: I've tried to add out.println("File uploaded sucessfully") inside the try, but nothing to show.

Comment: Try to print valid HTML. like this example: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Comment: If that is the totality of your method, then nothing happens if `isMultipartContent()` is false, so maybe that's your problem. Otherwise, since you're printing plain text, call `setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8")` before calling `getWriter()`.

Comment: it doesnt print for me after i used valid HTML.But Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
out.println("File Upload Failed due to " + ex.getMessage());
```

or

```
out.println("File Upload Failed due to " + ex.printStackTrace());
```

Comment: But i wanted to print a success message inside the try. The success message doesnt show after i use out.println.

Answer (score 0):

try to use doGet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("hey");
}
```

Comment: it printed out nothing also.